# How can I process listbox items and save them in a SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, database

I am using a multi-select listbox to show a date. I want to process all selected values and store them in my database.

How do I process all the selected dates and save them in a database?

Is it possible to store all the selected dates in a single row?

Is there an alternative for storing the value?

Answer (score 0):

This is too broard of a question to answer.

In regards to processing the selected values you can do something like this

```
foreach (ListItem listitem in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (listitem.Selected)
        Save(listitem);
}
```

In regards to database you can both save in one row and multible rows. It depends on what you want to do

Comment: Agreed.  Are you asking how to capture the values in the UI, or how to save them?  If both, I suggest two questions.